# Multi-party encryption in .NET?

Tags: .net, security, encryption

I learned about a multi-party encryption scheme in GnuPG, where multiple public and private keys allow many people to change and access shared information. Is there a similar library in .NET?

Furthermore, let's say one of the users forgets the passphrase protecting his private key. Is there a library that supports regenerating another private key, without affecting the other users?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by that last question? The only thing that is lost is the possibility to sign or decrypt for the user, and of course the trust of the accompanying public key stored by the others. Otherwise the other users would be just dandy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) crypto library has support for OpenPGP and a number of others.  It's a bit short on documentation, but it does support split keys.